# R programming Error "Failed to connect port 443: Timed out"

Tags: r

I am trying to read the webpage https://csmprod.service-now.com/navpage.do. This site needs credentials to login.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

content <- getURL("https://csmprod.service-now.com/navpage.do")
doc <- htmlParse(content, asText = TRUE)
```

Also I am hitting with 443 timed out error. Can anyone help on this?
But I am able to access the above site from browser.

And I need the code to parse user credentials and login automatically while reading.

Comment: The redirection is the problem. Works https://csmprod.service-now.com/csm/login.do and ss.verifypeer=FALSE

Comment: Thanks dieter.. I have tried the code that you provided. Seems to give the same error even now :(

Comment: There was a typo: `content <- getURL("https://csmprod.service-now.com/csm/login.do",ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)`

Comment: Yes I corrected it by myself.. So that should not be the problem :)
But error still occurs.. Just thinking connection is getting established..

Comment: Make sure your version of RCurl is uptodate. It maybe you are running an old version using SSLv3.

Comment: Hi dharrison, the version that I am using is "RCurl_1.95-4.5 bitops_1.0-6"
Can you advise if that is correct?

Comment: Have you solved this already? I met with this problem too